# Scale svg figure in html output of Sphinx (rest)

Tags: svg, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a figure in restructured text using a scale directive as follows:

```
.. figure:: images/my_image.svg
   :scale: 150 %
```

The the image is perfectly OK in the HTML output of sphinx, except that it is not scaled. (The svg image has width and height information and a viewBox)

It is strange, that in contrast to png figures, the `<img>` tag in the HTML file does not contain width and height attributes of the image (hm, can't sphinx determine width and height of the svg for some reason?).

What is the reason for this? Does sphinx support the `:scale:` directive for svg figures?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try setting the width. This can also be assigned a percentage of the current line width as value.

```
.. figure:: images/my_image.svg
   :width: 100%
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Georg. This is a good idea, however it is not exactly what I want. If I assign a percentage to the width, the image is scaled according to maximal space available. 50 % does not mean 50 % of the width of the image, but 50 % of the current width available, which depends on the window size.

Comment: @AndreasGschossmann Yes, I know it does not exactly answer your question but it may serve as a reasonable workaround.

Comment: Yes it is a good workaround, and it comes closest to what I want to do. I really appreciate it. I also thought, that you know that and just added the comment for completeness.